# What are the good reading books to learn cluster algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, cluster-algebra

What are the good reading books to learn cluster algebra? I need a basic introductory books or notes in particular. I do not have any physics background and I want a book which starts with graph theory. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point you will want to read Fomin and Zelevinsky's papers: [I](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104151) [II](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208229) [III](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305434) [IV](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602259). There are also video lectures from Lauren William's course at the [Institut Henri Poincaré](https://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/CA.html) with several resources linked on that page. There's also a draft of a textbook by Fomin, Williams and Zelevinsky on the arXiv in two parts: [1-3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05735) [4-5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07190).

Answer (score 3):

There are some lecture notes like

1) https://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/papers/CA.pdf

2) http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/philipp.b.lampe/LectureNotes/cluster.pdf

3) https://bookstore.ams.org/emszlec-19

In general, you do not need any Graph theory know to a huge extent. I have to be familiar with quivers, edges and all.